React Native got error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
React Native got error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
When I want to used GoogleMap in my project, but I got the this error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
I used this plugs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api
and step by step to install.
but I don't know why I got the error.
this is my code
function GoogleMapSection({coordinates,listing}) {
   
    const [center,setCenter]=useState({
        lat: 40.730610,
        lng: -73.935242
      })
      const [map, setMap] = useState(null)
      const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: 'google-map-script',
        googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY
      })
      useEffect(()=>{
        coordinates&&setCenter(coordinates)
      },[coordinates])
     
      useEffect(() => {
        if (map) {
          
            map.setZoom(10);
        }
    }, [map]);
      const onLoad = useCallback(function callback(map) {
        // This is just an example of getting and using the map instance!!! don't just blindly copy!
        const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(center);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        setMap(map)
       
      }, [])
      const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        setMap(null)
      }, [])
  return (
    <div>
        <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={center}
        zoom={10}
        onLoad={map=>setMap(map)}
        
        onUnmount={onUnmount}
        gestureHandling="greedy"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default GoogleMapSection


This usually happens when Google Maps API is not properly loaded or initialised. However, with the information provided in your question, it's difficult to pinpoint exactly why it's not loaded or initialised. If you can provide the code for your app.js and any other relevant code, I can help you diagnose the error.

in my project, I don't have app.js file. Only has page.js & layout.js. I upgraded the information. @AbdelDjeebet

You are using a NEXT_PUBLIC environment variable, is it a React project or React Native?

Please note that react-google-maps/api is only for web implementation. What you should use for React Native implementation of Google Maps is react-native-maps.
The react-native-maps has a MapView component and to specifically use Google Maps, you should add the property provider=PROVIDER_GOOGLE to your <MapView>.
But to make sure that things work fine, I'd suggest that you follow the expo quick start guide by creating your app using npx create-expo-app <your-app-name> and read through the expo documentation to learn more.
ref: https://docs.expo.dev/
Here's an example using Google Maps:
import React from 'react';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView style={styles.map} provider=PROVIDER_GOOGLE />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

Then follow this guide to make sure that you have set things up properly like the API KEY.
